# Android studio, gradle tries to download non existed sha1 from maven url

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to add library to my project ([this one](https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library))

I added proper url to build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://drgames.fr/maven2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then I am trying to use it in project

```
implementation ('com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:2.0.4-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

However, every time I sync project with gradle files, it tries to download metadata for all files under this maven url:

```
Metadata of http://drgames.fr/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.2/espresso-core-3.0.2.pom  186 ms
Download http://drgames.fr/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.2/espresso-core-3.0.2.pom.sha1    80 ms
Download http://drgames.fr/maven2/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/3.0.2/espresso-core-3.0.2.pom 71 ms
```

And the result is tons of errors, during downloading sha1 (but I still can run my app which uses described library and it works):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<html"
```

When I run building from command line (./gradlew build) there is no errors.

My questions are:

1) What is this magic sha1 file? Why it can't be downloaded and why gradle tries to do it everytime?

2) How to get rid off this errors?

Answer (score 0):

this `sha1` file most likely is a `HTTP 404` page. just exclude `com.android.support.test.espresso` from that dependency and substitute it with the default one, from repository `mavenCentral()`:

```
implementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
implementation ("com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:2.0.4-SNAPSHOT") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support.test.espresso", module: "espresso-core"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "appcompat-v7"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
}
```

Comment: But I have about 100 different pom that gives me error. I checked that this files aren't even used by this multi bluetooth library.
I tried this solution and gradle still tries to download espresso from drgames.fr url

Comment: @user3361462 it rather seems to me that you've added a Maven project as dependency into a Gradle project ...just fetch the jar/aar and add it locally, or build with Maven. the `SNAPSHOT` even hints for, that there may be source code available, in order to build with Gradle.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by 'added a Maven project as dependency into a Gradle project'? The only thing I did with maven was adding maven key/value to repositories in app.gradle. And I am getting all errors even without adding any lib from this url to dependencies.